# How to install and configure the latest ODBC driivers for both MYSQL & PostgreSQL in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mysql, postgresql, odbc

I'm currently trying to get access to some MYSQL and PostgreSQL databases via an ODBC connection via an ODBC Administrator GUI as I had on Windows. After searching around, I have only found scattered and old tutorials for installing and setting up ODBC connections on Ubuntu.

Can someone help me with a more up to date instructions as I am working in a delicate production environment so the last thing I need a screwup? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer only explains how to install MySQL ODBC drivers.  I guess for Postgres, you will have to ask the drivers from Postgres.  See this page for more info on that: http://www.unixodbc.org/, under the theme 'Drivers'.

1. Install UnixODBC

> sudo apt install unixodbc

2. Get and install the MySQL drivers from MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/. That will create the files `libmyodbc5X` (where the X depends on which driver has been installed) and `libodbcmy.so` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc`. The first one is the driver, the second is the managing driver (not very useful).
3. Create two files in `/etc`: `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini`
   The first one contains the specification of the available drivers. In your case, there will be two of them, one for MySQL, the other one for Postgres.  The second one is the collection of database source name.  Each one specifies at least a name, between brackets [], and a driver name.

For example, my `odbcinst.ini` contains:

```
[MySQL]
Description= MySQL ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc5w.so    
Usagecount=1
```

and my `odbc.ini`contains two entries, one for the production database, one for the test

```
[Prod]
Description = Production DB
Driver = MySQL
SERVER = 127.0.0.1
USER = youruser
PASSWORD = yourpassword
PORT = 3306
DATABASE = prodDB

[TestDB]
Description = Test DB
Driver = MySQL
SERVER = 127.0.0.1
USER = youruser
PASSWORD = your password
PORT = 3306
DATABASE = test
```

From that point on, you can connect just using the DSN name (Prod or TestDB).  Of course, it might be wise to put your username/password elsewhere.  The exact way to connect to DSN depends on the programming language/development tool that you use.

Answer (score 4):

You should always periodically copy your production environment to a test environment for user training and a development environment for yourself. You don't want your trials and errors effecting production (the company's bottom line) or user training (they are already enough challenge day to day without messing up their world).

That said, here are some newer ODBC (Open Database Connection) tutorials for you:

- [April 11, 2019 Connect to PostgreSQL Database on Linux, Windows](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/connect-to-postgresql-database.php)
- [August 16, 2019 MySQL show status: How to show open database connections](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/how-show-open-database-connections-mysql)

Comment: Updated the question I want to set up the ODBC connections to the databases on Ubuntu using something like an ODBC  gui manager where I can manage all the ODBC database connections.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to install any of the 4 drivers for Ubuntu 20 from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

But I do have a list of files in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/ directory:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14304 Jan 14  2019 libesoobS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14264 Jan 14  2019 libmimerS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 88992 Jan 14  2019 libnn.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14200 Jan 14  2019 libodbcdrvcfg1S.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14176 Jan 14  2019 libodbcdrvcfg2S.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14200 Jan 14  2019 libodbcminiS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14232 Jan 14  2019 libodbcmyS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14200 Jan 14  2019 libodbcnnS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14296 Jan 14  2019 libodbcpsqlS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14240 Jan 14  2019 libodbctxtS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14600 Jan 14  2019 liboplodbcS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14176 Jan 14  2019 liboraodbcS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14304 Jan 14  2019 libsapdbS.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14176 Jan 14  2019 libtdsS.so
```

Will any of them work for me to use in the odbcinst.ini file?

When I try to install any of the 4 deb files I get this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> mysql-connector-odbc-dbgsym : Depends: mysql-connector-odbc (=
> 8.0.32-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Thank you.